# extjs 4.2 treepanel bufferedRenderer scroll to specific node

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, treepanel

I use ExtJS 4.2 and bufferedRenderer for large tree. when i need to scroll specific node I have to use **grid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(rowIndex)** as in 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html

but when I do not have row index but only node object how can I scroll to it? If all tree nodes expanded - it is simple: I have to count all previous nodes, but if some nodes collapsed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
grid.getView().scrollRowIntoView(rowIndex)
```